# Set Raster Data with Byte Array

Tags: java, arrays, byte, bufferedimage

I have a question about Rasters in BufferedImage. I have a byte array of image data, and I want to set that byte data as the new image data. I've already seen way way of doing this, pictured below:

```
   BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = new BufferedImage(dimWidth, dimHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
   byte[] bufferHolder = ((DataBufferByte) bImageFromConvert.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
   System.arraycopy(imageInByte, 0, bufferHolder, 0, bufferHolder.length);//imageInByte is my byte array  
   ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "bmp", new File(
                directory + fileName + "_Compressed.bmp"));
```

However, while writing the data to the bmp, the final result isn't what was expected. I've been hammering my head over this project for days, and I want to see if I can put the byte data directly in the Raster to see if that makes a difference. I'm sorry if this question is a bit confusing, my brain is a bit fried from the hours of coding. Please let me know if there's any way I can make it more clear.

Thank you!

EDIT: Output image
[clilck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1FI6.png)

EDIT2: Side note, does anyone know why the bytes seem to be repeating like that in the output image? The code that separates out the high and low bits doesn't seem to be duplicating anything.

Comment: What are the results that you are getting that are not what you were expecting?

Comment: Are you trying to apply your byte array `imageInByte` to `bImageFromConvert`?

Comment: @CraigR8806 I'm writing stacked image byte data to an image, and the intended result is to have the high bytes appear at the top of the image as a really "bright" mini-image, and the low bytes at the bottom as a darker mini-image. Right now it looks like the high byte and low byte images are being repeated twice. I'm wondering if it's because of multiple color channels? But I was pretty sure that TYPE_BYTE_GRAY gave me an unsigned 8-bit grayscale image. I'm very confused why this repeating is occurring. I'll attach my image output so you can see what i mean.

Comment: @CraigR8806, yes, I'm trying to put imageInByte into bImageFromConvert.

Comment: The error is not in the code you have posted. I suggest you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as described in the help center, to highlight the problem and get better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done to copy a byte array into an image with a DataBufferByte is the fastest and safest way to do it. I do exactly the same thing and it works perfectly.

Consequently, if the result is not what you expect, then there are only two possibilities:

1. the data you copy into the DataBuffer are not what you thing they are
2. there is an issue when you write the image.

If you want to use the raster instead of the DataBuffer, you can do as follow.

```
for (int y=0, pos=0 ; y < dimHeight ; y++)
    for (int x=0 ; x < dimWidth ; x++)
        bImageFromConvert.getRaster().setSample(x, y, O, imageInByte[pos] & 0xFF) ;
```

But it must be exactly the same result of what you've done before. The Raster just manages en BufferedImage encoding for you. So I do think that you have an issue elsewhere (see the two points I cited).